# How much of “À la recherche du temps perdu” is autobiographical?

Tags: french-language, marcel-proust, in-search-of-lost-time

To what extent is it an account of Proust's own life? How much is made up?

With so much detail (it's *thousands* of pages long), and knowing a little bit about the life of the author itself, it'd be natural for a reader to think that the series is autobiographical (Proust was after all a sensitive kid with very weak health and a passion for literature living among the upper classes in France). However, I have read somewhere that it is not, strictly speaking, an autobiography. There are a few hints of this: the narrator is never named, and many place names are made up.

So I would like to know what parts of the story are fantasy, and what parts are direct experiences and acquaintances of the author.